# Reading csv file in python. Do I have an issue of wrong encoding?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have downloaded 700 large csv files (excel csv files). The file has comma separator and 15 columns. However, in some rows there are 16 columns. This is because one of the columns is countries where I have e.g. "Korea, South" creating an 16th row (the data is not surrounded by "" unfortunately).

So my issue is if I load one of the csv files with pandas.read_csv() I have to skip bad rows (those with South Korea) and I want to keep these.
`df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, encoding="utf8", header=0, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True, engine='python')`

So I went on to use with open() and edit rows with South Korea

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    
    csv_read = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    
    for row in csv_read:
        
        search_terms1 = ["Korea"]
        search_terms2 = ["South"]

        if any([term in row[2] for term in search_terms1]) and any([term in row[3] for term in search_terms2]):
            row[2] = row[3] + row[2]
            row.pop(3)
        
        if any([term in row[4] for term in search_terms1]) and any([term in row[5] for term in search_terms2]):
            row[4] = row[5] + row[4]
            row.pop(5)
        
        ARRAY.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(ARRAY)
```

I first tried this method on some dummy data I made and it worked great. With the original file, however, it does not work. I get following.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 82: character maps to <undefined>
```

I belive this error occures because the file include russian, arabaic etc. So i have tried specifying the encoding, but none seems to work. In above I think the encoding is bydefault set to 'cp1252' as Iam on Windows.

utf-8 does not work, because it can not deal with arabic.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 18: invalid start byte
```

utf-16-le also gives warning

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 14-15: illegal encoding
```

cp437 gives following

```
Error: line contains NULL byte
```

I have tried several more encodings. All errors happen at

```
----> 37     for row in csv_read:
```

NOTE: I use VS code where the encoding is set to 'utf-8' on a windows. Ido not know if this info is usefull.

So my question is:
How do i read this file without losing my bad lines? Is this an issue of wrong encoding or should i use a different approachto read the file?

Comment: UTF-8 can represent any character in Unicode, including Arabic. The problem is apparently that the file isn't encoded with UTF-8. If the file contains Russian, Arabic, and Korean text, then I'm pretty sure it's encoded in one of the UTFs (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-23), because I don't think there is another encoding that can support them all at once. Note: for UTF-16 and UTF-32, there are LE and BE variants, but Python should autonmously pick the right based on the BOM at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Of course it's also possible that the file contains a mixture of encodings, which basically means it's corrupt. Given that the CSV formatting isn't well-formed, according to you, it's not that unlikely that the creator messed up the encoding too :-(

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Python 2? If so, consider using https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/ instead of the built-in `csv` module. You should be able to just install it with pip, then `import unicodecsv as csv` to make it a drop-in replacement.